# Reloading Jupyter Widgets for rapid development

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter

I am currently working on a custom Jupyter Widget. When I include the necessary javascript using `%%javascript` magic in the notebook I can simply reload these cells to update my widget if I make changes, which is handy for development.

Is there a way you can do this type of easy reloading with the javascript stored outside of the notebook? Because right now I have to completely restart Jupyter when I want to see the effects of a change.

A related question: when I store the javascript externally, Jupyter somehow still knows where to find it even though I don't load it explicitly. Where does Jupyter look to find the javascript for custom widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so apparently I just wasn't diligent enough in clearing my outputs, which is why I got weird results. I post my solution below in case it helps other people.

I have my javascript in separate .js files. I load this into my notebook by having a cell with the following content:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
with open("javascript.js") as f:
        data = f.read()
text = """<div style="overflow:auto">Loading scripts</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
{}
</script>""".format(data)
display(HTML(text))
```

The execution of this cell inserts the necessary javascript. When the underlying javascript files have changed, just rerun the cell to update the javascript. Then when you instantiate a new widget, it will have the updated code.